# XCODE 5 with ios5 project developed using XCODE 4.6

Tags: xcode5

every time i try to run the project in new XCODE 5 the build fail and i got that error:

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
>   failed with exit code 255